# How do I reference tag values in HTML

Tags: html, forms, select, input

I have this code:

```
<select name ="selected">
   <option>
      Option1
   </option>
   <option>
      Option2
   </option>
</select>
<input name = "text" type = "text" value = "The value of the selected value of the drop down list"/>
```

How do I reference the value of ***selected*** in the value of ***text***?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: HTML is a static language. If you need to that, use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery,

`alert(Value is "+$('select[name="selected"]').val());`

Answer (score 0):

To give a slightly expanded answer, combining what some have already said in the comments, there are a couple of things you should know:

1. HTML is "static" document markup - it does not pull values from other elements, etc. It simply marks up existing content.
2. If you want behavior as you describe, you will have to use a scripting language that's supported by a web browser... particularly, you will use Javascript. ('jQuery', mentioned in another answer, is a framework written to make Javascript programming for webpages easier. It's worth looking into, once you understand the concepts here).

I recommend checking out the Web Fundamentals course on http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web which will probably be a great help to you, at this point.